# snowflake substring with pattern

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

A column in sf table has values like

```
test/SalesID
test2/SalesIDaccount
mytempSalesID
1234SalesIDnum
...
```

I want to substring this column to show only

```
SalesID
SalesIDaccount
SalesID
SalesIDnum
```

so remove everything before SalesID and keep whatever left. How to approach it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [regexp_substr](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/regexp_substr.html#regexp-substr)

```
select regexp_substr(col, '.*(SalesID.*)', 1, 1, 'e', 1) as "RESULT";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`split_part()`](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/split_part.html).  To get the *last* component:

```
select split_part(col, '/', -1)
```

To get the *second* component:

```
select split_part(col, '/', 2)
```

It is not clear if you want the last, second, or if it doesn't matter.

Comment: thanks @Gordon Linoff  sorry for not being clear, the pattern is the string starting with 'Sales', so i need to remove everything before Sales and keep whatever left.